# How to hide and show the buttons located inside a grid in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

I have a grid looking something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    title: 'myGrid',
    store: 'myStore',
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name'},
        { text: 'Running', dataIndex: 'running' },
        { 
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            text:'play or stop',
            items:[
                {
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-play-circle',
                    handler:function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex){ play(); }
                }, {
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-stop-circle',
                    handler:function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex){ stop(); }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

It works fine. In the third column there are two buttons: a "play button" and a "stop button". Now they are always visible but I want the play button to be visible only when `running==false`, and the stop button to be visible only when `running==true`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the getClass config, which can be specified for the actioncolumn itself or for child items of the actioncolumn. [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-items)

Then you can just do something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    title: 'myGrid',
    store: 'myStore',
    columns: [
        {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'},
        {text: 'Running', dataIndex: 'running'},
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            text: 'play or stop',
            items: [
                {
                    getClass: function (value, metadata, record) {
                        return record.data.running ? '' : 'x-fa fa-play-circle'; 
                    },
                    handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        play();
                    }
                }, {
                    getClass: function (value, metadata, record) {
                        return record.data.running ? 'x-fa fa-stop-circle' : '';
                    },
                    handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        stop();
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: This is close to the answer

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    title: 'myGrid',
    store: 'myStore',
    columns: [
        {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'},
        {text: 'Running', dataIndex: 'running'},
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            text: 'play or stop',
            items: [
                {
                    getClass: function (value, metadata, record) {
                        return record.data.running ? 'x-fa fa-stop-circle' : 'x-fa fa-play-circle'; 
                    },
                    handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                        playOrStop();
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```